# PCB Design Software for work collaboration and minor alterations?

Tags: pcb-design, dfm

In my workplace I need PCB software to make minor changes to PCB layouts from our design partners and also to review and suggest changes to incoming designs.

Our design partners use x and y.  X is used for our 8 layer product while y was used for a feature to be controlled by our main product.

For example, on our main product, I want to make minor placement corrections to allow a wave process to be used during manufacture for a small number of through-hole components, whilst on the y companion piece, I want to change a relay.

I have no requirement to work with FPGA's.  It would be nice if there was some DFT/ DFM analysis but it is not a requirement.

What package should I use to allow me to meet our requirements?

**Editted so as not to refer to specific products.**

Comment: If your design partners use Altium and DesignSpark why would you choose something different with all the possibilities of slight incompatibility?

Comment: @JImDearden you can strike "possibilities" and "slight" for most of the packages on that list, if not all.

Comment: @Asmyldof I was being generous a bit tongue in cheek. Its a 'no brainer'

Comment: @JImDearden I hoped so, but I wasn't sure. :-)

Comment: Wow, hadn't expected this level of abuse.  Obviously, the reason is cost.  We cannot justify altium at the moment.  As I'm sure you're aware altium can output to multiple formats.

Comment: I understand your situation.  Unfortunately there is little interoperability between EDA packages from different vendors.  Regarding this level of abuse: welcome to EE.SE.  Don't expect that we suffer fools or take prisoners.  ;)

Comment: I am a fool for asking a question? What's the purpose of this site then? To insult people looking for help?  Should I wait around until someone needs help on ic interconnect modelling, (my masters thesis), and then tell them they are a fool?

Comment: Regarding interoperability, mentor were onsite and assured us that altium could export to their format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify Altium boards, use Altium and ignore the features you don't need (or pay someone to do it for you). Caution that if you don't use it deeply and often enough it may be difficult to maintain a high level of efficiency and competency- in my experience all full EDA suites are quirky and complex and occupy significant mental bandwidth.

As I understand it Designspark is free so there is no downside to trying to use it to make minor mods.

You have not mentioned cost - in real life that might be a consideration. Altium, for example, will cost many thousands and thousands more for maintenance.

Comment: Yes, cost is the reason.  A previous post was shut down for discussing cost so I tried to phrase it in such a manner that the noobs would not attack it.  Unfortunately no luck there...

Answer (score 0):

You use whatever the designer uses. If you want the designer to use something else, you put that in the contract.

There is no point in saving $10000 now by not buying an Altium License and get something cheaper and then having to call the designer to do a $20000 repair on your highly unfunctional files saved by something that turned out to not be actually as compatible as they said on the website.

The reason companies like Altium spend a lot now internally on offering cheaper packages than the long term established and working with educational projects is that they get a generation of Altium designers that then imply Altium at their next jobs, which then causes all their contacts to have to buy it as well. Because this stuff is just not cross compatible.

Comment: Thanks for replying, would up vote but no reputation.